# How do I make words of certain length flip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, loops, iteration

So I'm trying to create a program that takes sentences and makes words of length 5 or longer reverse itself. At the moment it is only flipping the last word that meets the condition and I don't know why.

```
userInput = "Hello this is a test sentence"
wordList = userInput.split()

for i in wordList:
    if len(i) >= 5:
        reversedWord = i[::-1]
        print(reversedWord)
        reversedSentence = userInput.replace(i, reversedWord)

print(reversedSentence)
```

Instead of outputing "olleH this is a test ecnetnes" it outputs "Hello this is a test ecnetnes"

Comment: You always take the original string for the replacement.

Comment: Python has a function `reversed`, which may be clearer to use than `i[::-1]` here. Replacing `i` with `word` probably also makes things clearer.

Comment: Replacing `i` with the meaningful name `word` is a good idea. But if you use `reversed` you'll have to rebuild the string yourself (e.g. `reversed_word = ''.join(reversed(word))`).

Comment: It might look terribad but shows that you can to a lot with just join, split and list comprehension: `print(' '.join([(word if len(word) < 5 else ''.join(reversed(word)) )for word in userInput.split(' ')]))` x)

Comment: @garglblarg Of course the obvious solution is `print(' '.join((lambda x: x[::2*(len(word) < 5)-1])(word) for word in sentence.split()))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You keep replacing the original `userInput`

```
reversedSentence = userInput
for i in wordList:
    if len(i) >= 5:
        reversedWord = i[::-1]
        print(reversedWord)
        reversedSentence = reversedSentence.replace(i, reversedWord)
```

You need to keep updating the reversedSentence variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

The actual bug in your code has already been stated, I just want to add some feedback regarding the style:

You are performing the following steps:

- split the input into words
- find words that meet your requirement (`len(word) > 5`)
- change the original string for each of those

This is rather unconventional and a bit unintuitive (it also has bad performance, since it manipulates your original string multiple times). I recommend the following algorithm instead:

- split the input into words
- reverse the words meeting your requirement *inside that list*
- join the list into a sentence again to get your string

Example implementation:

```
user_input = "Hello this is a test sentence"
processed_words = []

for word in user_input.split():
    if len(word) >= 5:
        word = word[::-1]
    processed_words.append(word)

reversed_sentence = ' '.join(processed_words)
print(reversed_sentence)
```

Taking this idea a bit further by using a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), it might look like this:

```
user_input = "Hello this is a test sentence"

reversed_sentence = ' '.join(
    word[::-1] if len(word) >= 5 else word
    for word in user_input.split())

print(reversed_sentence)
```